# Why scale of my new UI texture differs so much comparing to other GUI elements?

Tags: unity

I have created an UI Texture and set Texture to my .png file. The size was only 256x256 but in the canvas it appears huge. I can change it to minimum 2x2 which is still big.

If I compare it to other elements that are 135x135, they are a lot smaller... [image]

So why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the Pixel Per Unit on the texture?

Comment: How can I check that? Btw it's been fixed already, I just had to go back few steps (Ctrl+Z). Though I still wonder.

Comment: where you import the texture